# Angular link not firing when data changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of items where each item is bound to a directive.  When the array is first built, all is well, but when I reset the array to new values, the link functions for the directives do not fire. Here's the HTML, where each element of the frame array contains a number of items, each of which is bound to my directive, cool-chart

```js
var app = angular.module("theapp", []);


 app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
$scope.frames = []
   $scope.getData = function() {
     var frames = ["adsf","qwerty"];
     alert("got new Data")
     
     $scope.frames.push(frames)
    
   }
   
 });

 app.directive('coolChart', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     scope: {
       data: '=data'
     },
     link: function(scope, element) {
       data = data.toUpperCase();
       alert("Link called with: " + data)
     }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="theapp">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    {{frames}}asdf
    <button ng-click="getData()">run get Data</button>
    <div class="outer-frame" ng-repeat="frame in frames track by $index">
      {{frame}}
      <div class="chart-container" ng-repeat="item in frame track by $index">
        {{item}}
        <cool-chart data="item"></cool-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You'll note that you see the alert "got New Data", but the directive link function is not invoked.

Am I thinking of this wrong?  What's the right pattern here to replace the array contents so that the data bound at each of array elements triggers the correct change notifications?

Comment: The link function is invoked, however the link function needs to refer to "scope.data" instead of just data. My answer below has the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try not breaking the reference to initial frames array when you reassign it...instead try emptying it and merge new data into it so reference isn't lost

```
// declare empty array on scope
$scope.frames = [];
var getData = function () {
    // reset scope array
    $scope.frames.length = 0;
    // merge data into frames
    $scope.frames.concat(data); // not sure where data comes from
 };
```

Alternatively if data is being brought in from event outside of angular you would need to tell angular to run digest with $apply()

I took out the `while` loop because I didn't see why it was needed

Comment: it won't work as is because concat doesn't modify "this", but in the spirit of your post, I did set $scope.frames length to 0 then did the pushes there... no luck.   I have tried mucking around with $apply, but am not completely clear where... when I've tried to call it this context, I always get an error saying a $digest is already in progress.  For what it's worth, have also tried $timeout, but even though I see the array emptied, when the data is repopulated, the directive is not notified.   The while loop is tangential to the discussion, but needed in that it groups elements into frames

Comment: I never need to do this anyway myself and angular is pretty good at new references...can you make demo that replicates problem? When data is wrapped in $http it will call $apply whcih is likely why you are getting digest in progress...was only suggestion if data was coming from outside angular

Comment: check out my updates to the original question (I used much of the sample of another respondent).  I'm pretty sure I'm thinking through this incorrectly and that angular doesn't think the objects have changed (i.e., it's still using the object bound when the original array was created), but I'm not clear how to make it work or how to dig further.

Comment: try getting rid of track by and see what happens. Also try upgrading angular at least into 1.3 series, is now into 1.4

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a code snippet that resembles much of your code. And it seems to work when you run the snippet. If you can, please edit your question in a similar fashion to try to address the issue    :)

Updated: now the link fires the alert as expected.

```js
var app = angular.module("theapp", []);


app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.frames = []
  $scope.getData = function() {
    var frames = ["adsf", "qwerty"];
    console.log("got new Data")

    $scope.frames.push(frames)

  }

});

app.directive('coolChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      data: '=data'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.data = scope.data.toUpperCase();
      alert("Link called with: " + scope.data)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="theapp">
  <div ng-controller="controller">
    {{frames}}asdf
    <button ng-click="getData()">run get Data</button>
    <div class="outer-frame" ng-repeat="frame in frames track by $index">
      {{frame}}
      <div class="chart-container" ng-repeat="item in frame track by $index">
        {{item}}
        <cool-chart data="item"></cool-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - I've adopted it in my question.  Did you note that your alert in the link function did NOT fire.  I added another alert to confirm the "got data" fires (and that alerts in general fire in this context).  I also added a call to toUpperCase to be a proxy for manipulation of data (which in my real code is regenerating a d3 chart).  If we can "fix' this sample so that the upper case is applied, I think that will translate to my code as well.

Comment: The answer has been updated and now it should fire the alert as expected. Notice the scope.data in the alert. Hope this helps.